# Android: Daylight Saving Time issues

Tags: android, date, timezone, timezone-offset

Have encountered some issues with DST (currently checked only on Galaxy Tab 2 10.1, android 4.2.2)

If i ask for current time in milliseconds:

```
Log.v(TAG, "Current time millis: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
Log.v(TAG, "Current date millis: " + new Date().getTime());
```

It will output incorrect time, that in one hour smaller. (for example if current real time is `1421336873000` it will output `1421333273640`).

Next, date parsing:

```
String dateStr = "2015-01-15T14:30:00 GMT+00:00";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss Z");
Date date = dateFormat.parse(dateStr);
Log.v(TAG, "Date: " + date);
Log.v(TAG, "Formatted: " + dateFormat.format(date));
```

Will print:

```
Date: Thu Jan 15 18:30:00 GMT+03:00 2015
Formatted: 2015-01-15T18:30:00+0400
```

In first case we have correct time zone (+03), but time should be 17:30:00
In second case printed time is correct, but timezone is wrong...

Slightly confused, how this can be handled?
I need to get printed correct time: 2015-01-15T17:30:00+0300

**P.S.**

Calling `inDaylightTime` returns false.
`getDSTSavings()` returns zero
`getRawOffset()` and `getOffset(..)` always returns 4 hours

Comment: According to [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) you may try ZZZZ instead of just one single letter Z in your pattern in order to parse the component "GMT+00:00".